# Sql select statement returns Null reference error in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am view specific category of item in a view. I want it to view all products under that category when clicked but I get a null reference exception. I have seperate tables for the category and products.

Here is what I tried.
Code in view:

```
@model IEnumerable<OpabidFarmsLtd.Models.ViewModels.Shop.CategoryVM>

<h3>Categories</h3>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">All</a></li>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li><a href="/shop/category/@item.Slug.ToLower()">@item.Name</a></li>
}
 </ul>
```

And my controller (ShopController):

```
public ActionResult Category(string name)
    {
        // Declare a list of ProductVM
        List<ProductVM> productVMList;


        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            // Get category id
            CategoryDTO categoryDTO = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Slug == name).FirstOrDefault();
            int catId = categoryDTO.Id;

            // Init the list
            productVMList = db.Procucts.ToArray().Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId).Select(x => new ProductVM(x))
                .ToList();

            // Get category name
            var productCat = db.Procucts.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId).FirstOrDefault();
            ViewBag.CategoryName = productCat.CategoryName;
        }

        // Return view with list
        return View(productVMList);
    }
```

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4wwq.png)

Edit:
While looking for what is wrong, I discovered that the method Category never got the parameter at all, I commented all the codes in it and did this:

```
 public ActionResult Category(string name)
    {
        string cat;
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            CategoryDTO dto = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Slug == "test-category").FirstOrDefault();
            cat = dto.Id.ToString();
        }

        return Content(name + cat);
    }
```

It returned only 8 which was the Id from the database. I know why it was giving me null, it was because it never received any parameter then default to null. What I can't figure out now is why the parameter isn't getting there from my code above. Please help, I am new to this framework.

Comment: Where's the SQL statement that fails?

Comment: int catId = categoryDTO.Id;

Comment: `db.Categories.Where(x => x.Slug == name)` there mustn't be any `CategoryDTO`'s that satisfy that condition.

Comment: You get a Null Reference Exception because the previous line that sets the `categoryDTO` variable ends with `FirstOrDefault`. The query didn't find any results, so it assigned the variable the default value for that type (a `null`). When you try to access a property of a null object you get that exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I have a field in my database named Slug, I don't really understand why it won't find it

Comment: @Davidire and there is a row that has the value referenced by `name` in the Slug column?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes

Comment: And you verified that your app is connecting to the same database that you're looking at?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to send "productVMList" to view but you add categoryVM model to html page. I think you should send "categoryVMList" instead of "productVMList" or you should add productVM to your view. Like;

`@model IEnumerable<OpabidFarmsLtd.Models.ViewModels.Shop.ProductVM>`

Also you should use .Add to add new item to the list. For example,

`ProductVMList.Add(object)`

Otherwise, put breakpoint to `return View(ProductVMList)` and check list null or filled.